# scilab - program to find position of zero

Tags: scilab

```
255 255 255 255 255 255  0   0  0  0 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255  0  255 255 0  0  0  255 255
255 255 255 255  0  255 255 255 0  0  0   0  255
255 255 255  0  255 255 255 255 0  0  0   0   0
255 255 255  0   0   0   0   0  0  0  0   0   0
255 255 255  0   0   0   0   0  0 255 255 255 0 
255 255 255 255  0   0   0   0  0 255 255 0  255
255 255 255 255  0   0   0   0  0 255 0   0  255
255 255 255 255 255 255  0   0  0  0  255 255255
```

How can I find by using scilab functions, the zero at row 5 and column 9 (5*9)

Answer (score 0):

Saying that your matrix is saved in "data.dat" you can first read the matrix from the file and store it in a variable (here "M") using:

```
M = fscanfMat('/<add filepath here>/data.dat');
```

The next step is to find the matrix elements which equal 0. This can be done using:

```
[row, column] = find(M == 0);
```

Where "row" is a (1-by-n) vector containing the row indices of the elements equal to zero and "column" contains the column indices of found elements, respectively.

If you are interested in how many zeros there are found you can use

```
n = size(row, 'c')
```

which tells you that there are 53 zeros found.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

Say I want to find exactly the location of the zero at row 5 and column 9. 
What i mean is, I want scilab to tell me that this zero is at row 5 and column 9 without using linear indexing. Its like finding the zero in the centre.

Is there any command for this?

Comment: @gluthra: Actually I'm a beginner in using Scilab, so I don't know whether Scilab provides such a function. What you could do is calculate the index of the middle column and the middle row. After that you could access the middle element of your matrix and check whether this element equals zero using an if-statement. If my suggestion would solve your problem and you need some algorithm for that, don't hesitate to comment on my comment. Btw: Your question seems to be very similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525558/scilab-program-to-find-the-position-of-the-zero-in-the-centre)